# why does the fetch request not work when I try to fetch a markdown file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, fetch-api

I am trying to display a markdown file from my computer to the browser window with fetch, but the response (text) is undefined, why is this happening? I leave a codepen with my code.

https://codepen.io/matiasConchaSoto/pen/popvQgp

```
<main>
 <h1>Blog con Markdown y ShowDown</h1>
</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/2.0.3/showdown.min.js"></script>
<script>
 const d = document,
 $main = d.querySelector("main");

 fetch("./assetsPropios/javascript.md")
 .then(res => {
   console.log(res);
   res.ok ? res.text() : Promise.reject(res);
})
 .then(text => {
   console.log(text);
   $main.innerHTML = text;
 })
 .catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
   let message = err.statusText || "Ocurrió un error";
   $main.innerHTML = `Error ${err.status}: ${message}`;
 });
</script>
```

Somebody help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `.then()` has a missing `return`.

Try:

```
return res.ok ? res.text() : Promise.reject(res);
```

Even better, something like:

```
if(res.ok) {
    return res.text(); 
} else {
    throw new Error(res.statusText); // or some message of your own choice.
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how I didn't notice something like this, thank you very much.

Comment: Easily done. Been there, bought the teeshirt.